# canvas при уменьшении картинки экран не очищается

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

не мгоу разобраться почему, вроде всё должно работать, функция doCanvas вызывается, и работает отдельно. а при уменьшении масштаба она не стирает старый рисунок

```js
var img;
var tttScale = 1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function Move(a) {
  switch (a) {
    case 'plus':
      if (tttScale < 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale + 0.05;
      break;
    case 'mines':
      if (tttScale > 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale - 0.05;
      break;
    default:
      tttScale = 1;
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  doCanvas();
  ctx.scale(tttScale, tttScale);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  // alert(tttScale);

}

function doCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF8F00';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  //alert("111");
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('mines')" target="_self" id="a_33ff_4">Minus</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('plus')">Plus</a>

  </br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готовое решение = > https://jsfiddle.net/c7ffxtjj/

Выдает следующую ошибку - *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined*

- переменная `img.width` не инициализирована (добавь её в `draw()`)

Ну и еще.

- Для прорисовки картинок используй следующую функцию:

`function draw(options)
{
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = options.file || options.filename;
 ctx.drawImage(img, options.x, options.y, options.width, options.height);
}`

Где аргумент `options` - объект с параметрами `x, y, width, height, file` (или `filename`).

- для очищения canvas используй`ctx.clearRect();

В идеале подойдет следующее:

```
 var width = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].width,
     height = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].height;

 function clear(Options)
 {
    ctx.clearRect(Options.x, Options.y, Options.width, Options.height);
 }
```

Где `Options` - объект с обязательными параметрами `x, y, width, height`

Что бы закрасить canvas, если не нужно рисовать картинку можно использовать

```
function Rect(parameters) {
   ctx.fillStyle = parameters.color || 'black';
   ctx.fillRect(parameters.x, parameters.y, parameters.width, parameters.height);
}
```

где `parameters` - объект с обязательными значениями `x, y, width, height` и необязательным `color` (если его нет нарисуется красный квадрат)

- Для инициализации игрового цикла (постоянной прорисовки) используй эту заготовку => 
  window.onload = Start;

  var loop = function()
  {
  now = performance.now();
  dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now-last)/1000);

  while(dt > step) {
      dt = dt - step
  }

  last = now;

  Update(dt);

  requestAnimationFrame(loop); //repeat it again
  },
  last = performance.now(), step = 1/60, dt = 0, now;`

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

где используются `function Start` и `function Update`

Comment: а кто выдает ошибку? хром молчит..   добавил var img.width; - теперь вообще канвас исчез

Comment: Тут код нужно на хостинг закидывать, через jsfiddle не показано имя файла скрипта, если не хочешь переделывать под мои стандарты, просто после img = `new Image();` допиши` img.width = твое_значение`

Comment: Закинь скрипты на jsfiddle, я посмотрю

Comment: Переделывай короче скрипт

Comment: Сейчас скину линк на рабочий вариант если смогу сделать

Comment: Лови [https://jsfiddle.net/c7ffxtjj/]

Comment: Спасибо заработало

Comment: Залейте на обычный хостинг, должно работать. Если не работает - отпишите, завтра приду, попробую сам выложить на хостинг и напишу :)

Comment: я потыкал мышкой, завелось ) спасибо за помощь