# SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пишу игру и за пример взял [Путеводитель по играм HTML5 без слёз](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/putevoditel-po-igram-html5-bez-slez)

Пытаюсь соблюдать структуру как там, и для этого переписал часть своего старого кода. После этого он перестал работать и выдаёт ошибку

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ';'[Learn More]  snake.html:24:22а

Как исправить ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>  Snake </title>


        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  
  <style>#canvas { background-color: rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2); }</style>
  
  
  <script type = "text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    var dx = 0;
    var dy  = 0;
    

    var FPS = 30;
    setInterval(function () {

     function update();
                    function draw();
    } 1000/FPS);
    
                function update(){
                    dx++;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
                }
    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(dx, dy, 25, 25);
        
    }
             
    
   </script>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598404/canvas-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F/598411#598411 в теме есть мой ответ с полезными фичами для геймдева канвас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поставил комментарии в места с ошибками

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // стояла ; должна быть запятая, либо на следующей var, если это не глобальная переменная
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;


var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {

  update(); // лишнее слово function
  draw();  // лишнее слово function
}, 1000 / FPS); // пропущена , перед значением интервала

function update() {
  dx++;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(dx, dy, 25, 25);

}
```

Хорошего коддинга, и меньше ошибок!